# Add or subtract from random string between a min and max number

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Lets say I have a minimum number of 18 and a maximum number of 28. In a `for loop` I want to have a starting number between the min and max number and add or subtract 1 after every loop. How can I achieve this?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
const minimum = 18;
const maximum = 28;
  for (let i = Math.random() * (minimum - maximum + 1) + minimum ; i < 15 ; i+  Math.random()*2) {
    console.log ("Added" + i);
  }
```

But this just keeps looping infinitely

Comment: Please post some code to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework? Where's your first code attempt?

Comment: No it's not homework. I'm just trying to learn coding. @pixelearth

Answer (score 0):

Your mind is

1st time, rand 18 - 28.

2nd time, rand 19 - 27.

....

times..., rand 22 24.

```js
function random(min, max) {
  const crypto = window.crypto;
  let r;
  if (crypto) {
    const array = new Uint32Array(1);
    crypto.getRandomValues(array);
    r = array[0] / 65536;
  } {
    r = Math.random();
  }
  return Math.floor(r * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

(function() {
  let min = 18,
    max = 28;
  let r = [];
  while (min < max) {
    r.push(random(min, max));
    min++;
    max--;
  }
  console.log(r);
})();
```

Comment: You might want to read this also regarding random numbers in JS:  https://levelup.gitconnected.com/new-way-of-getting-random-number-in-javascript-using-crypto-9388cfbd2a3e

Comment: Thank you, This is an interesting knowledge